# record code behavior as PHPUnit tests before refactoring

Tags: refactoring, phpunit, code-generation, code-coverage, xunit

Let's say we have a (PHP) function with no site effects:

```
function xyz(a, b, c) {
    // 100 lines of code
}
```

I'd like to have a tool, that calls function xyz with all kind of different combinations of a, b, c and records the parameters and return values in form of unit tests.

Than I can use this tool to kind of "record" the behavior of a function before I refactor it. It would even be cooler, if the tool could interpolate the types of a, b, c and try to exercise all code paths through the function.

Is there such a tool for PHP or for other languages?

Answer (score 0):

Well you actually only need to create a sets of parameters, call the unit with it and keep track of the actual value.

Then after refactoring, run against the same set of parameters and check if the actual result is the expected one.

Let's say you've got a unit under test:

```
$unit = function() {
    return implode('-', func_get_args());
};
```

It's really a simple function. In the first round you capture the data, for example with permutated sets of parameters:

```
$params = new ParameterSetsIterator(range(0, 1), range('a', 'c'));

$dataset = [];
foreach ($params as $index => $args) {
    $actual = call_user_func_array($unit, $args);
    echo $index, ': ', $actual, "\n";
    $dataset[] = [$args, $actual];
}
file_put_contents('dataset.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($dataset, true) . ';');
```

Output:

```
0: 0-a
1: 1-a
2: 0-b
3: 1-b
4: 0-c
5: 1-c
```

You then can use such set by just including it and validating against it. If you want to keep it as regression test data-set (take care to reduce those sets to the really interesting values, not just to really large sets that just run through w/o fails all the time), you can also make use of them as a data-provider in Phpunit:

```
function provideSet() {
    return include('dataset.php');
}

/**
 * @dataProvider provideSet
 * @test
 */
function withSet($args, $expected) {
    $actual = call_user_func_array($this->unit, $args);
    $this->assertSame($expected, $actual);
}
```

As you can see, only your imagination is the limit.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm aware that I can do it _manually_. But a lot can be automated and my question is, whether somebody has already done the work to automate it.
Thank you though for the long examples and for hinting me to the ParameterSetsIterator.

Comment: I'd say my suggestion is highly automated. All you need to do is to think about how to create the initial datasets, the `ParameterSetsIterator` is actually just doing permutations of the given values. It not only takes array but also iterators, so you can easily introduce some generator that creates random values. I normally write such things my own and have them run in PHPUnit. On a higher level of system test you might want to test with fuzzer that injects data on the HTTP level and is able to replay these. I think Owasp has tools for that.